# Is it possible to access instances of a directive from inside the directive definition?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive for drawers that can be used in my application. What I want to do is this: When the user opens one drawer, I need any other currently open drawers to close.

This is my current code:

**Markup**

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="my_switch">
    Click me to toggle the drawer!
</a>
<drawer data-switch="#my_switch">
    Content of the first drawer
</drawer>

<a href="javascript:;" id="my_other_switch">
    Click me to toggle the other drawer!
</a>
<drawer>
    Content of the second drawer
</drawer>
```

**Drawer.html**

```
<div class="drawer_container">
    <div class="drawer" ng-transclude>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
MyApp.directive('drawer', function(DrawerService){
return {        
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'drawer.html',                     
    link: function(scope, element, attributes){         
            var drawer_switch = $(attributes.switch);
            var drawer = $(element).find('.drawer');

            var toggle = function(event){
                drawer.toggle();
            };

            drawer_switch.bind('click', toggle);
        }
    };
});
```

Is it possible for the opening of one drawer to cause the rest of the drawers to close by using only the directive?

Answer (score 0):

I would combine the directive with a drawer service. Use the drawer service to expose things that are needed to coordinate across various models, views, etc. For example, you can have each drawer directive register itself to the service (for example, send in a callback for notification). Then you can have a method on the service that when invoked will send a message to all registered drawers to close. This also makes it cleaner to implement because if anything else has to interact with drawers, they can interact with the service instead of the directive and remain decoupled from the UI implementation.

Comment: How can I get a specific instance of the drawer and feed it to the service then? Can I add open() and close() methods to the drawer instance so they can be closed from the service?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a controller that is shared amongst all instances of the directive.

From the AngularJS [documentation on directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

*controller - Controller constructor function. The controller is instantiated before the pre-linking phase and it is shared with other directives (see require attribute). This allows the directives to communicate with each other and augment each other's behavior.

You can refer to the Accordion directive that is part of the AngularUI Bootstrap project [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.js) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**

Even though I got some answers that pointed me to a good direction, implementing those suggestions took some extra homework. I'm presenting my findings here, as long as the current implementation.

Using [Jeremy Likness's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/228918/jeremy-likness) suggestion, I created a service that kept record of all the drawers. The issue I came up with is "*if not the DOM, what **is** a drawer?*". 
After some reading I found out that I can create a specific scope for each drawer using the `scope: true` option on the directive definition, so each scope instance refers to it's corresponding drawer.

**Drawer.html**

```
<div class="drawer_container">
    //Whether the drawer is visible is now being derermined here   
    <div class="drawer" ng-show="is_open" ng-transclude>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Service**

```
MyApp.factory('DrawerService', function() {
var drawers = [];
var drawerService = {
    // Adds the scope of a drawer to the drawers array. This method should be called when 
    // a new drawer gets created in order to be handled later
    addDrawer: function(drawer){
        drawers.push(drawer);       
    },
    // Closes all the drawers that are open, except for the one that is provided
    closeTheRest: function(drawer){         
        for(var i = 0; i < drawers.length; i++)
        {
            if(drawers[i] !== drawer)
            {       
                  drawers[i].$emit('forcedClose');
            }
        }        
    }
};

  return drawerService;
});
```

**Directive**

```
MyApp.directive('drawer', function($timeout, DrawerService){
return {        
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,       
    scope: true,
    templateUrl: 'drawer.html',               
    controller: function($scope)
    {
        $scope.is_open = false;
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attributes){                     
        var drawer_switch = $(attributes.switch);           
        var drawer = $(element).find('.drawer');

        DrawerService.addDrawer(scope);

        drawer_curtain.css({
        'height': $(document).height()
        });         

        scope.$on('forcedClose', function(){
            scope.is_open = false;
        });


        drawer_switch.bind('click', function(){
            scope.is_open = !scope.is_open;                 
            DrawerService.closeTheRest(scope);
        });         

    }
};  

});
```